# Dell Inspiron 15 3542 running Ubuntu 14.0.4 : Touchpad and wifi not woking

Tags: 14.04, dell

I bought a new laptop Dell Inspiron 15 3542, Ubuntu 14.04 is **pre-installed** in it but it seems that touch-pad and WiFi is not working.

Please help

Comment: If its pre-installed from the manufacturer, asking them may notify of problems and get it fixed for you. With the touchpad please can you add the output of `xinput` , with WiFi please see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/178596).

Comment: If it is pre-installed, it should work on first access. You should call the warranty